# UUIDv6, v7, v8 in Javascript (Browser)

Tags: javascript, uuid

I have been trying to find Javascript solutions for generating UUIDs in the browser. [The ones I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/3625228) generate UUIDs following the version 4 standard.

Example:

```js
function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  );
}

console.log(uuidv4());
```

or even

```js
let uuid = self.crypto.randomUUID();
console.log(uuid);
```

Are the other versions impossible to generate in the browser because they use MAC addresses (and those are inaccessible in JS due to privacy concerns)?

As I understand it, **V6** is mostly UUIDv1 with some reordering ([Draft](https://uuid6.github.io/uuid6-ietf-draft/)), so it's not possible to use either. But how about **V7** and **V8**? Is there an aspect preventing online (client-side) use? Or could the V4 code be adapted to produce those?

Answer (score 1):

Not a definitive answer, but I managed to piece together a solution for UUID v7 in the browser, after I read the [post by buildkite](https://buildkite.com/blog/goodbye-integers-hello-uuids), and a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/1557ugn/libraries_to_generate_uuid_v7/) on Reddit.

I modified the [UUIDv7](https://github.com/kripod/uuidv7) project to work in plain Javascript instead of Typescript. My modifications probably miss a bunch of edge cases, like `seq` always being `0`, but at least it's something to start with. I'll leave it here for others to tell me what I did wrong.

```js
function uuidv7 () {
    const UNIX_TS_MS_BITS = 48;
    const VER_DIGIT = "7";
    const SEQ_BITS = 12;
    const VAR = 0b10;
    const VAR_BITS = 2;
    const RAND_BITS = 62;
    
    let prevTimestamp = -1;
    let seq = 0;

    const timestamp = Math.max(Date.now(), prevTimestamp);
    seq = timestamp === prevTimestamp ? seq + 1 : 0;
    prevTimestamp = timestamp;
    
    const var_rand = new Uint32Array(2);
    crypto.getRandomValues(var_rand);
    var_rand[0] = (VAR << (32 - VAR_BITS)) | (var_rand[0] >>> VAR_BITS);
    
    const digits =
    timestamp.toString(16).padStart(UNIX_TS_MS_BITS / 4, "0") +
    VER_DIGIT +
    seq.toString(16).padStart(SEQ_BITS / 4, "0") +
    var_rand[0].toString(16).padStart((VAR_BITS + RAND_BITS) / 2 / 4, "0") +
    var_rand[1].toString(16).padStart((VAR_BITS + RAND_BITS) / 2 / 4, "0");
    
    return (
        digits.slice(0, 8) +
        "-" +
        digits.slice(8, 12) +
        "-" +
        digits.slice(12, 16) +
        "-" +
        digits.slice(16, 20) +
        "-" +
        digits.slice(20)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```js
const v4 = () => {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    const r = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 16);
    const v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

const v7 = () => {
  return 'tttttttt-tttt-7xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    const r = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 16);
    const v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  }).replace(/^[t]{8}-[t]{4}/, function() {
    const unixtimestamp = Date.now().toString(16).padStart(12, '0');
    return unixtimestamp.slice(0, 8) + '-' + unixtimestamp.slice(8);
  });
}

console.log(v4());
console.log(v7());

// Also see: https://gist.github.com/fabiolimace/c725349dd34aedc7b69867dabec59c08
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/fabiolimace/c0c11c5ea013d4ec54cf6b0d43d366c6